# How to check if iframe is empty/null/undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, iframe

This doesn't work:

```
if(document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML==''){
```

Is there a safe browser reliable way to check an iframe if its empty or not?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Are you trying to figure out if no page was loaded or if the loaded page is blank?

Comment: No page loaded... But both would be good to know...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well if you can use jQuery, check it's `length` property. This is cross-browser compatible. If it's zero, it doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
if(!$("#iframeid").length) {
    // iframe doesn't exist
}
```

**EDIT:**

After seeing your comments on your question:

If you want to check if no page loaded inside iframe, and the iframe is not *cross-domain* you could check for the existence of the `body` tag inside of the iframe. If it exists, then something loaded.

Something like this:

```
if($("#iframeid").contents().find("body").length) {
    // some html page loaded in iframe
}
```

If the iframe is cross-domain, you will be blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Otherwise this will work.

Comment: Returns true all the time it seems... Not working in ohter words... I will try the other method of finding "body"

Comment: I used if(iframe.offsetHeight==0) to find if it is there or not... I mostly need to know when it is NOT there, so suits my needs and works in major browsers :)

Comment: @alex : how to do it for cross domain

Answer (score 4):

Check the frame's `contentDocument` property.  IE 7 and earlier support the `contentWindow` property instead, but there is a simple cross browser example at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp.

A less-reliable method but might be what you want... check the `src` property.

You can read about other frame properties at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp

Answer (score 0):

The  check of  iFrame emptyness can be achieved using  Jquery as defined  below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($("#iframeId").contents().find("body").is(':empty')) {
        // Apply ur logic
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.