# how to hide an iframe if content is empty

Tags: javascript, iframe, hide, is-empty

I am using iframe in which I am displaying some content from external url. I want to hide the iframe if there is no content to display (i.e empty). please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Please show the code where you get content!!

Comment: <iframe src="http://.../Blue/Current/" id="blue" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" >
           </iframe>

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check content from external url inside iframe is empty, and the iframe is not cross-domain you could check for the existence of the body tag inside of the iframe. If it exists, then something loaded. Well if you can use jQuery, check it's `length` property. This is cross-browser compatible. If it's zero, it doesn't exist.

**CODE:**

```
if($("#iframeid").contents().find("body").length) {
    // some html page loaded in iframe
}
```

If the iframe is cross-domain, you will be blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Otherwise this will work.

SOURCE: [How to check if iframe is empty/null/undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215952/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-empty-null-undefined)

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery .content() to evaluate the content of the iframe and .hide() to hide it.
If you want to show it again latter use .toggle() instead.

Answer (score -1):

**No.**

This cannot be done by a script on the calling page. The calling page will not be able to access the external document object loaded inside the iframe due to *cross-domain security restriction*.